# Subversion and Symfony 2

Tags: svn, symfony

My team is about to begin a web project using the Symfony2 framework. We will be using SVN for version control (this is non-negotiable, sorry git fans). I am trying to conceptualize how we will be able to revision code as well as deploy to our live server smoothly.

Here's the general system we are working with:

- SVN Server
- Deployment Server
- Each team member should develop locally on their own machine

How I would like our system to work:

- Developer checks out website code to local machine
- Develops through Eclipse IDE
- Debugs, tests, and launches local copy of site on their machine (connects to deployment server to access DBs)
- Checks changes into SVN repo
- Updated code is deployed to the live server by lead developer

Does this seem like a good work flow? The only awkward part about this is that it will require each developer to deploy a W/LAMP stack to their local machines. But, that is still feasible.

Also, is their any tools or commands specific to Symfony/SVN that will make this workflow easier to implement?

Comment: Sorry for offtop but curious why svn, and not mercurial/git in y2012?

Comment: This is for a software engineering class, and this is their constraint. Also, the team is most familiar with SVN.

Comment: I've learnt about a dozen of people who used svn for years how to use mercurial in about half an hour. And all of them said thank to me after they realized how cool mercurial is ;-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, I was under the impression that it requires some sort of commercial license to use. Is this true, or is their a free version?

Comment: it doesn't. Mercurial as well as git - are completely free-for-any-usage SCMs

Comment: Note: there's a git-svn bridge, meaning you can use git locally and svn on the server. If you would prefer git otherwise, it's worth checking out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything looks fine and obvious except of one thing

> Updated code is deployed automatically to the live server

**DON'T DO THAT**

Indeed, deployment is a process performed automatically, **but** it **always** should be initiated by user. Always, with no exceptions

Also I'd add another step - continuous integration server, to run your tests and calculate various metrics and make some analysis

Comment: Good point! This could certainly lead to problems if a developer checks in broken or buggy code.

Comment: @user8709: just today I've watched these slides: http://www.slideshare.net/kastner1/deployinator-turning-the-fear-into-the-fear - I hope they also would help you to set up your pipeline

Answer (score 1):

See some points of possible future headache:

1. If

> Developer checks out website code to local machine

How to ensure from propagaded **local-only** data (configs?)

1. If every dev

> connects to deployment server to access DBs

you haven't any solution for situation "we changed structure of database" and from "data out of sync" disaster, when you *got* solution

1. Items 3,4,5 **together** look like a provocation to work with giant sporadic mixed commits instead of "commit often, commit fast"
2. I didn't see *any* mention of **automated** unit and functional tests

Comment: To ensure the developer doesn't check in unnecessary local configs, then we will ignore any such files when committing to the repository. I do see your point about the database, though. It is something I will consider. Furthermore, we do plan on using automated unit tests, and I envision the developer running the test suite locally before a code check-in to ensure everything is working.

Comment: @user8709: and tests should be run by continuous integration server as well

Comment: @user8709 - and got another *bad trip*, when **data-structure** of configuration will be changed on developer's side (same situation as DB)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read the [*How to Create and store a Symfony2 Project in Subversion*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_svn.html) cookbook entry.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest CI like Hudson auto deploy after each commit.

Deploy written in ANT:

Clear-Cache
Drop-Database
Schema-update
Load-Fixtures

Run PHPUnit Tests